# TCPDF generated PDF shows blank on Mac Preview and Safari

Tags: macos, pdf, safari, tcpdf, preview

But it has no problem when opened in Google Chrome. When I opened it with Safari/Preview, I got a blank page. Zooming in/out does nothing.

Below is the code I used for generating the PDF files:

```
require_once('../vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // get the current page break margin
        $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
        // get current auto-page-break mode
        $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
        // disable auto-page-break
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
        // set bacground image
        $img_file = '../assets/img/background.jpg';
        $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 150, 90, '', '', '', false, 150, '', false, false, 0);
        // restore auto-page-break status
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
        // set the starting point for the page content
        $this->setPageMark();
    }
}

$pdf = new MYPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, [150, 90], true, 'UTF-8');

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Kent');
$pdf->SetTitle('Title Here');
$pdf->SetSubject('Subject Here');
$pdf->SetTopMargin(44);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 44);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML('This is the content.', false, false, false, false, 'C');
$pdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/output.pdf', 'F');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 reasons for this problem , first please use absolute path, secondly your pdf does not open in  adobe acrobat either. it is because your image is missing icc profile . open your photo and save it again in Photoshop or similar software.